# Автоматический выбор языковой версии сайта на PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на Wordpress и 2 языка UA и RU. Локализация сделана путем создания копии сайта в нужном языке на поддомене типа ru.mydomain.com

Задача.
 - Запоминать выбор локализации пользователем для дальнейшей загрузки нужной ему локализации.
или
 - Определить язык браузера и выводить нужную локаль зависимо от этого

Я нашел варианты решения:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038236/http-accept-language

пример кода (найденный в свободном доступе. Автор кода - PHP Программист [XyZ])

```
// действие с проверкой языка и установкой куки языка проводим только на странице index.php
if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/index.php") or (substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], -1)  == "/")) {

// если вход произведен без указания языка
if (!$_GET['lang']) {

    // то проверяем, может язык указан в куках, если нет, то то смотрим локализацию браузера
    if (!$_COOKIE['lang']) {

        $b_lang = explode(",", $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]);

        // если локализация русская или украинская или белорусская, то считаем, что пользователю необходимо отдавать русскую версию сайта.
        if (($b_lang[0] == "ru") or ($b_lang[0] == "be") or ($b_lang[0] == "ru-UA")) $lang = "rus";

        // при всех остальных локализациях отдаем английскую версию
        else $lang = "eng";

    }

    // если язык уже указан в куках, то его и используем в системе
    else $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}

// если страница запрошена с указанием языка, то этот язык и используем в системе, и запоминаем его в куку
else {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time()+30758400, "/");
}

}
```

Суть работы предложеных вариантов понял. Но я только начинаю разбираться с php и не знаю как написать саму так сказать "механику" подгрузки нужной локали.

Answer (score 2):

PHP код для определения если нет куков.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) { //Если нет куков
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2); //Определяем язык браузера
    if ($lang != 'ru') {$lang = "ua";} // Если не украинский - то ставим русский, по умолчанию
    setcookie('lang', $lang); 
    $_COOKIE['lang'] = $lang; //Записываем в куки
}
```

Далее переменную $lang использовать в функции перенаправления.
Не знаю каким образом выбирается язык у вас на сайте, но пускай это будет две ссылки. Тогда добавить обработчик js, что бы пользователь мог выбирать язык и браузер запоминал его выбор.

```
<a href="#" class="lang" id="ru">RUS</a>
<a href="#" class="lang" id="ua">UA</a>

$('a.lang').on('click', function(){ //Обрабатываем клик по выбору языка
    document.cookie = "lang="+$(this).attr("id"); // Записываем в куки язык
});
```

Все в упрощенном варианте. Для адреса можно добавить GET запрос, что бы передавать ссылку сразу на нужную версию сайта. Могу написать, если потребуется.

Comment: язык, 2 кнопки/ссылки типа mydomain.com и ru.mydomain.com
> Могу написать, если потребуется. 
Спасибо, пожалуйста напишите

Comment: Я думаю нет смысла обрабатывать GET запросы, если у вас и так два разных домена. Просто добавьте функцию перенаправления.

Comment: `header('Location: http://'. if ($lang = 'ru') {echo "ru.";} .'mydomain.com'); ` Примерно так, только пропишите еще условие, необходим ли редирект, что бы он не был бесконечным. Я думаю путем сравнивания текущего URL с тем на который будет происходить редирект. Либо проверка на вхождение языкового поддомена.

Comment: > только пропишите еще условие, необходим ли редирект, что бы он не был бесконечным.   
К сожалению не умею. Читаю, изучаю сейчас работу функции редиректа php